# Json in html template

Tags: python, json, bottle

I use bottle to print some json in html template, so I do in template:

```
% for rows in url:
    <ul>
        % for cols in rows[0:2]:
            <li>
            {{cols}}
            </li>
        % end
        % for req in rows[2:3]:
        <li>
            {{req}}
        </li>
        % end
    </ul>
% end
```

Result:

- http://www.adress/
- 1.5
- {'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options':
  'nosniff', 'age': '2295260', 'expires': 'Fri, 08 Dec 2017 08:32:02
  GMT', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'sffe', 'last-modified':
  'Thu, 08 Dec 2016 01:00:57 GMT', 'connection': 'close'}

But I want in the last item of list to make another list,
so if I do

```
% for list in req:
   {{list}}
% end
```

I get

- x
- -
- x
- s
- s
- ...

Does anyone have any idea to print the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just insert an inner loop

```
...
% for req in rows[2:3]:
    % for line in req:
        <li>
            {{line}}
        </li>
    % end
 % end
```

If it always the last item you can also just loop over it

```
...
% for line in rows[-1]:
        <li>
            {{line}}
        </li>
%end
```